# PostgreSQL and Blazor .Net Core 3.1

Tags: npgsql, blazor

Are there any resources on how to use the current version of Blazor (3.1) and PostgreSQL?

I've tried writing the simplest code, just to see whether it connects to the database but I get this error message: `System.Net.Dns:GetHostByName is not supported on this platform`

a button click would activate this code:

```
async void connection()
{
  var connString = "Host=Server1;Username=postgres;Password=pass;Database=BlazorData";

  try
  {
    await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    errcheck = "success";
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     errcheck = ex.Message;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I explain how I use it with entity framework. It might help you.
in startup.cs, ConfigureServices method have this

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

You need two packages to be installed through nuget

```
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design
```

in appsetting.json make sure you have setup connection string correctly, below one is mine. Host can be localhost if database is in the same machine as the database

```
"DefaultConnection": "Host=192.168.16.240;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=mypassword;Database=mydatabase;"
```

That's basically it.

then define a application db context with your tables

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Meal> Meals { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
    }
```

in package mangaer console

```
add-migration initial
update-database
```

you should see the tables created in PgAdmin.

and use your dbsets like usual c# lists. and remember to inject applicationdbcontext in the controllers you need it.

Comment: I'm not sure `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design` is necessary at all. The official *Npgsql* documentation doesn't mention it (https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html) and it didn't receive any updates in the Nuget store since 2016 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design/1.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

The error says you need to resolve the hostname by yourself. Either pass an IP address or use [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Dns_GetHostEntry_System_String_)

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
...
async void connection()
{
  var host = Dns.GetHostEntry("Server1");
  var firstIpV4Address = host.AddressList.First(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
  var connString = $"Host={firstIpV4Address};Username=postgres;Password=pass;Database=BlazorData";

  try
  {
    await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    errcheck = "success";
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     errcheck = ex.Message;
  }
}
```